# What is the Depth reached by chess-AI agents on a regular computer?

Tags: chess, computer-ai

I'm looking for some **reference** for the number of lookahead steps typically used by chess agents (Stockfish / Leela Chess Zero / others?)

From a quick search I found that:
the answer depends on:

1. complexity of position,
2. computer hardware/processor speed,
3. efficiency of software/graphics interface,
4. time given to the chess engine.

with somewhat mediocre hardware a **depth around 15 ply's in one second** is typical.

the NPS value for the Stockfish engine: 49,473 kN/s (calculating 49,473,000 positions (nodes) per second).

source:

1. https://www.quora.com/What-is-Stockfishs-depth-when-analysing-a-chess-position
2. https://chessify.me/blog/nps-what-are-the-nodes-per-second-in-chess-engine-analysis

Comment: You may have better luck asking this at the chess stack exchange (https://chess.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: link to the question at chess.stackexchange.com
https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41183/what-is-the-depth-reached-by-chess-ai-agents-on-a-regular-computer?noredirect=1#comment67315_41183

Comment: If you include endgame table bases, that probably makes the number rather large.

Comment: @acccumulation you right, I am interested in stats that do not reach endgame tables.